# Integrate Ant builder into Eclipse: Relative paths for refresh scope working set

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

This question is similar to [Integrate Ant builder into Eclipse: Error "Variable references empty selection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793046/integrate-ant-builder-into-eclipse-error-variable-references-empty-selection), but asks for something different.

In my Eclipse JDT project, I have some ant tasks that I want to execute before compilation, so I added an ant builder to my Eclipse builder config. Now I want to configure the two options "refresh resources upon completion" and "working set of relevant resources" for this builder so that they contain a specific directory in my project.

Both allow me to specify a "working set" with this [dialogue](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/edit-refresh-working-set.png). The problem is that this will put paths in the Eclipse builder configuration file that are relevant to the workspace, and thus the paths will include project names.

The problem is that the whole project is managed in a subversion repository. The Eclipse configuration is part of the repository, and other users check this out with different file-system layouts and possibly different Eclipse project names. For example, I usually have several working copies of the same project in my Eclipse workspace, each of course with a different project name.

That's why I am looking for a way **how to specify a working set in Eclipse relative to the project directory** (not the workspace directory), or **some other way to define the refresh scope of a builder such that it includes a single directory in my project**.

I am using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

If I configure the working set in the dialogue and look in the configuration file afterwards, the following string is the value of the `ATTR_REFRESH_SCOPE` option:

```
${working_set:
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&#10;
&lt;resources&gt;
&#10;&lt;item path=&quot;/MyProject&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#10;
&lt;/resources&gt;}
```

Sanitized this looks like:

```
${working_set:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources><item path="/MyProject/lib" type="2"/></resources>
}
```

So I want to get the "MyProject" part out of this. I tried the solution of the question mentioned above and replaced the path with `${build_project:/lib}`. This gives no error message, but it seems to have no effect (Eclipse will not refresh the mentioned directory).

I also tried replacing the whole working set definition with `${build_project:/lib}`, but this gives an error message `Unable to restore resource memento`.

I know that I could just tell Eclipse to refresh the whole project after the builder is run, but this is not what I want (its quite slow). Also for the "relevant resources" configuration option, this would mean that the builder needlessly runs after every change in the project.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: No, I'm still looking for a solution. Thank's for adding a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Eclipse is not great with relative directories.

[Relative Paths in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280209/relative-paths-in-eclipse)

However you can do the following:

- Create a new workspace.
- Import files from a known location that will be the same on all machines.
- Configure everything inside of that known directory.
- Provide workspace and setup instructions to other developers, so that they will use this same 'known directory'.

You could have something like

```
C:\YourKnownDir\
    \workspace\
    \src\
    \build\
```

and start eclipse with a batch file:

```
start %ECLIPSE_DIR%\eclipse.exe -data .\workspace
```

If you're going to be included .project files in SVN, there should really be a predetermined full path. EG:

```
C:\svn
```

Hope that helps, but I don't know any other way to tackle this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible for me. I really need paths relative to the project directory, not relative to the workspace, for example to enable multiple instances of the same project in my workspace. Also everything else would be very inconvenient for the other developers, which are not all in my team (the project is open source). A full absolute path like `C:\svn`  is even less possible as most developers work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding one folder level in repository? Lets add the project in one folder in repository. so that whenever project is checked out it creates a folder with project name.
Currently if you checkout project in folder workspace1. It must be looking like:

```
workspace_1\lib
```

If you add one folder level in repo i.e. the name of project(e.g. `MyProject` here), everybody who checks out the project will get same project name. and multiple copies of project will look like

```
workspace_1\MyProject\lib
workspace_2\MyProject\lib
```

This way u can create multiple copies of project with same project name always and your script can exploit this uniqueness of project name always.

Comment: I don't want to use multiple Eclipse workspaces (as this would mean having multiple copies of Eclipse running simultaneously). Also it doesn't look like `workspace_1/lib` currently, the paths are `workspace/project_copy1/lib`, `workspace/project_copy2/lib` etc. And the repository structure cannot be changed in my case (OSS project).

Comment: new workspace is not necessary. i used it as just example. if you have project name level directory in repo and if u create multiple copies, it would look like `workspace/project_copy1/MyProject/lib` or  `workspace/project_copy2/MyProject/lib`

Comment: if you cant change repo structure and still want common ant script for all users, I would suggest that, go ahead and create a script with fixed project name. In this case all other users of this project will be mandated to create project copy with same name. I think common folder name is must for problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve the problem. The `MyProject` folder in the project changes nothing about the fact that there is still the varying project name in the path. And I can't rely on a fixed project name because I need the same project several times in the same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Completely different approach:

I think the limitations of shared Eclipse config files (i.e. config files committed to SVN) are quite large; some people prefer having their dependent libraries as source on disk, others prefer JAR references; each user's project names and workspace relative locations are different, and so on. And as you saw, lots of options are relative to either the project location (i. e. cannot refer to other projects) or the workspace location.

As I usually have Maven build files anyway, I use maven-eclipse-plugin to generate Eclipse configuration files from them. There are several options to choose from at runtime, and almost everything can be customized in the build file (and if not, just plug a plugin into that plugin that does what you want, and ship it with your build. Maven will automatically build that plugin if needed for the users who use it). And also some more abstract settings are shared between plugins, so if anyone insists in using Netbeans instead of Eclipse, he will at least get a rudimentarily configured project (dependencies, JRE versions, character sets, etc.) without me ever having used or even configured Netbeans.

Positive side effect: When adding or updating a library dependency, only one place (Maven POM) needs to be updated, the rest can easily be regenerated.

I'm sure this is not everyone's approach (especially if you use Eclipse not only for development, but also for building your final artifacts, using another build system may look like overkill).

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I've chosen to refresh "The project containing the selected resource" (as you already said, it does not depend on project's name) and marked with "Derived resource" as much folders as possible (Properties of folder -> Resource -> checkbox "Derived"). Eclipse will refresh derived resources, but not try to validate/rebuild/etc.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however, I do not yet understand it. How does marking resources as a "Derived resource" prevent Eclipse from refreshing them in this case? Also, which resources do you mark as derived? Your source files? Won't this pose other problems?

Comment: It does not prevent Eclipse from refreshing, it prevents rebuilding/revalidating files. This works for big XML/HTML files.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In this case, it does not work for me (I do want to rebuild if something has changed, I just want to prevent the useless slow refresh of the whole project when I know that only a few files have changed).